# css transition not working properly in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, css, transition

i use for loop to change className of "group of divs have same className" to make change of appearance by the change of heigth using css transition affect. But the problem is just the first div take affect and others keep quite.

html:

```
<body onload='init()'>
    <div id="menu">
    <div id="chosen" class="accor hide">od</div>
        <ul>
            <li>To</li>
            <li>Pr</li>
            <li>La</li>                
        </ul>
        <div class="accor hide">En</div>
        <ul>
            <li>fa</li>
            <li>Co</li>
            <li>Co</li>                
        </ul>
        <div class="accor hide">Sp</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.accor + ul{
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
.hide + ul{
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
```

javascript:

```
function init(){
    var chosen = document.getElementById('chosen');
    chosen.onclick = toggleDivs;
};

function toggleDivs(){
    hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('accor hide');
    for( var i = 0; i <= hideDivs.length; i++)
        hideDivs[i].className = 'accor';
};
```

with that code, when i click  the div with id='chosen', i hope that all divs with className: 'accor hide' will spread down like slidedown of jquery but just the first div do that.

if i change little bit of javascript code, it will be done with 2 divs take affect.

changed javascript:

```
function toggleDivs(){
    hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('accor hide');
    hideDivs[0].className = 'accor';
    hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('accor hide');
    hideDivs[0].className = 'accor';
};
```

i suppose that the version with for loop code, after i = 0, so first div take transition affect and the loop break out, it is really strange to got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function init() {
  var chosen = document.getElementById('chosen');
  chosen.onclick = toggleDivs;
};

function toggleDivs() {
  var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('accor')
  for (var i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++)
    menu[i].classList.toggle('hide');
};
```

```css
.accor + ul {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
.hide + ul {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<body onload='init()'>
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="chosen" class="accor hide">od</div>
    <ul>
      <li>To</li>
      <li>Pr</li>
      <li>La</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="accor hide">En</div>
    <ul>
      <li>fa</li>
      <li>Co</li>
      <li>Co</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="accor hide">Sp</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yeahhh, it work. Thanks u very much. But i really don't understand the stituation. Can u explain more. Other man give me the answer like just change hideDivs[i] become hideDivs[0] in toggleDivs function because hideDiv will remove after change but i still not got it.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` keeps tracks of your document current state. That is, once you change your element's className into another value, `hideDivs` will remove that element. Debug in the for loop to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('accor hide');

"hideDivs" here is a live HTMLCollection of found elements refer [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
.An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live. it will get updated automatically when the underlying document is changed.

So when you update class name of one of the element it will be removed from the variable "hideDivs". Hope this answers your question.